# Laravel: What are models?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm confused as to what models are and do in Laravel. I've tried to find some explanations but couldn't find any.

Can someone briefly explain what models are, when I would use them, and why I should use them?

More so, what are `fillable` and `guarded` attributes? I don't find they're very well explained in the docs.

For example, I have a table in my database, called `login_log`, that contains all login attempts. Would I create a model for this? Why?

Comment: You should probably look into people's code if you don't think docs are not helpful, also I think this question would have been already asked. Read this post http://hndr.me/blog/laravel-mass-assignment-protection-blacklist-vs-whitelist/

Comment: Laravel has some of the best documentation. Use it.

Comment: there do not appear to be models in laravel. Though, true enough models in other frameworks largely double efforts of DB reads, they make it eloquent to work with DBs/data as objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model is represented by M when you talk about MVC which stands for Model, View and Controller.

In Laravel Model is simply your database table object. This allows you to interact with your database tables as if they are PHP objects or classes.

Fillable property is used to tell laravel to allow mass assignment for the listed fields

while Guard property is the opposite of fillable

Laravel documentation is the best documentation so far.

Answer (score 0):

See this Links to Understand well : [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) in [Eloquent ORM for Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

#### Suggestions:

> If you are newbie in Laravel, as I am Android Application Developer
> i've find solution and understood too.
>
> You have to learn documentation before putting question.

Comment: Please read my question. "More so, what are fillable and guarded attributes? I don't find they're very well explained in the docs."

Comment: Have u seen `Mass Assignment`? There is all specification. You may do not have to create for your `login_log`

Comment: Yes, I've seen Mass Assignment.

Answer (score -2):

As MVC stands for Model View Controller, Model Deals with Database for example controller ask to Model to give me the first names of Students from the student table an d then controller pass it to the view.